# Sql queries difference

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I would like to know whether this two versions are equivalent in result and which is better for performance reasons and why?
Nested Select in Select version

```
select 
 t1.c1, 
 t1.c2, 
 (select Count(t2.c1) from t2 where t2.id = t1.id) as count_t 
from 
 t1
```

**VS**

```
select t1.c1,t1.c2, Count(t2.c1)
from t1,t2
where t2.id= t1.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query is analog of this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.c1,
  t1.c2,
  COUNT(t2.c1)
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

It selects all records from first table, and all matched records from second table (it is **LEFT JOIN** condition).

The second is analog of this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.c1,
  t1.c2,
  COUNT(t2.c1)
FROM t1
  JOIN t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

It selects only matched records in both tables (it is **INNER JOIN** condition).

Comment: "The first query is analog of this query ..." Yes, but only of `t2(id)` is the primary key or unique.

Comment: @Devart: Just to clarify something, my first query `count(t2.c1)` if there is matching between `t1.id` and `t2.id` while in your suggetion this will work if and only if `Count` function doesn't count `nulls` , am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Well they are different queries.  The top one will select all rows from t1 returning 0 for the count if there is no matching id in table t2.

The second query will only return rows where t1 and t2 both have a row with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

The first query will likely suffer from performance issues on large data sets.  The second query will potentially have a Cartesian issue.  I would go with a join or left join based on your intent to have records from table 1 if table 2 has no related records and then add a group by statement to control the Cartesian.